# spamassassin does not honour local.cf

Tags: ubuntu, exim, spamassassin

I updated my `/etc/spamassassin/local.cf` spamassassin file to update some score rules. However, even after restarting spamassassin (via service), the new score are not shown in spam emails. In fact, nothing in that file seem to influence how spamassassin work. Even adding a nonsense line does not cause any messages in the log file or on the `service spamassassin restart` command line.

I use exim as my MTA but that should not matter.

All packages were installed via apt-get and are at the latest version for 12.04.

Any idea?

Comment: And you don't have the same settings overruled by your personal `.spamassassin/user_prefs`?

Comment: No.  Those settings are not present in `~/.spamassassin/user_prefs` at all.

Comment: Just checked on my CentOS box and they use `/etc/mail/spamassassin :(`  what location does your `man Mail::SpamAssassin::Conf` give?

Comment: @HBruijn: It says: "SpamAssassin is configured using traditional UNIX-style configuration files, loaded from the `"/usr/share/spamassassin"` and `"/etc/spamassassin"` directories. [...] 
site-wide ("local.cf") and user-specific ("user_prefs") configuration files [...]".  So, I guess I have the right file.